# How to compare values in different tables and change the output in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know much about PHP so please excuse my inexperience. Here's my problem.

I have 3 tables [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7VNb.jpg).

I provide the user with checkboxes containing the values from table LOCAIS and CORES.

If checked, the values are sent to the table INFO (I use implode, that's why you see rows with more than one number).

What I need to do is this:

When outputting the data from table INFO to the user, I need to change the values from columns LOCAL and COR for their respectives values in the tables LOCAIS and CORES.

I don't want to change the values in the database, I just want to change the output based on the ID, in this case:

```
info.local = locais.id = locais.local
2, 3 = 2, 3 = Portugal, Suiça

info.cores = cores.id = cores.cor
1 = 1 = Azul
```

PS: Table INFO has more columns. Each row is connected to a user ID so I can filter the entries and display it to the specific user.

I tried a lot of things that didn't work but that was probably because of my inexperience.

So how can I do this?

---

**Edit 1:** I need to display all the information from the row of table INFO and change the values shown based on the other two tables. So if in the table INFO the row has these values:
"ID: 1 Local: 1 Cor: 2, 3"
the output would be
"ID1, Local: "Brasil, Cor: Verde, Vermelho".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

info.local = locais.id = locais.local info.cores = cores.id = cores.cor

I'm assuming that when you selected the checkbox and inserted it into the database, you concantated it into a single string?

A better way to do it would probably be to tweak your database structure, so that you can link the id to corvalues and local.

However, if you insist on doing it this way,

Assuming that info.id = userid, you will be pulling out one info row per table. For example, where ID = 1, the sql query would be to

```
SELECT LOCAL FROM INFO WHERE id = 1
```

After that, fetch the results in PHP. Going off the previous assumption that you concatenated the numbers into a string,

```
$localarray = explode(',', $output_from_mysql);
```

This will explode the string by commas and place them into an array. We now have the values of each local id in an array.

Iterate through this array and use the value in this query below to get the value.

```
SELECT LOCAL from LOCAIS WHERE ID = $current_array_value
```

Hope I understood the question right :)

Comment: Hi @elanor, thanks for the help. The info.id = the ID of that row (auto_increment), the ID of the user is in other column not presented in the image. I edited the question to try explain myself a little better. When I insert the checkbox in the database I use this: implode(",",$_POST["idofcheckboxes[]"]).

Comment: How are you storing the values 2,3,4 in your INFO.LOCAL? As a string 2,3,4?

If so, woud the logic above not work fine? simply use the logic for locals and repeat it with COR

To get the entire INFO table, you can just do a SELECT LOCAL FROM INFO and iterate through the results with a foreach

Comment: It worked beautifully! I didn't know much about foreach so took me some time to make it work, but it worked! Thank you so much for the great help!

Comment: No problem, please mark this as the selected answer if it resolved your issue :)